# Aggregate push N number of array results

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I have the following aggregate:

```
db.reports.aggregate({ $group: { _id: "$user", reports: { $push: {report: {properties: "$properties"} } }}}, { $project: { _id: 0, user: "$_id", reports: "$reports"} })
```

I would like to somehow limit the number of reports that get pushed into the array.  I.E I want to limit reports to a users defined value. 1,5,10 etc.  Meaning I want N number of reports (I will sort by timestamp) to be included in the reports field.  Right now I am pushing all reports not sure how to limit the number of reports per user.

I tried the $limit, but that didn't work as it restricted the number of users returned not the number of reports pushed into the reports array.

Basically I want to group my reports by user, and include only a certain number of reports.  I would like to limit the number of reports as early as possible such that I do not have to deal with the entire collection throughout the pipeline

Comment: You can easily do it with mapReduce. I am not sure that you can simply do it with aggregate. the $slice operator is unfortunately not supported in the aggregation for now.

Comment: Is there a way to limit the number if reports per user in some other fashion with aggregate?  IE if I was not pushing into an array.  Maybe do a couple groups in the pipeline.

Comment: I don't know if it is possible. But someone else may suggest an idea. Meanwhile, you can try the my reduce to solve your problem.

Comment: @innoSPG thanks for the response. Unfortunately reduce is a bit too slow so I moved to aggregate. If I can solve with aggregate I will probably just have to change my data model a bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you looked into using [group()](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.group/)? Let's say your data looks like this:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("732"), "user" : "john", "reports" : [  "report1",  "report2",  "report3" ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("733"), "user" : "john", "reports" : [  "report4",  "report5",  "report6" ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("734"), "user" : "max", "reports" : [  "report1",  "report2",  "report3" ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("735"), "user" : "max", "reports" : [  "report4" ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("736"), "user" : "eliza", "reports" : [  "report1",  "report2" ] }
```

Assuming reports is an array in the initial schema, your aggregation call becomes:

```
var reduce_f = function(curr, result) { 
  result.reports = result.reports.concat(curr.reports); 
}; 

var finalize_f = function(result) { 
  var limit = 5; 
  result.reports = result.reports.slice(0, limit); 
};

db.reports.group({ 
  key: { user: 1 },
  reduce: reduce_f,
  initial: { reports : [] },
  finalize: finalize_f
})
```

Note that group will **not** work in a sharded environment.